# Github ci failed with Appsweep Task 'uploadToAppSweepRelease' not found in root project

Tags: android, android-studio, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to use GitHub action to upload the app to AppSweep but i get `Task 'uploadToAppSweepRelease' not found in root project 'NewsHub'.`
this is the github action file:

```
name: AppSweep mobile application security testing
  on: [pull_request_target]
jobs:
  upload-app-to-appsweep:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
 steps:
  - name: Check out repository code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
  - name: Make gradlew executable
    run: chmod +x ./gradlew

  - name: Update Username from Secrets
    env:
      API_KEY: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}
    run: echo API_KEY="$API_KEY" > ./local.properties

  - name: Upload app to AppSweep with Gradle
    env:
      APPSWEEP_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.APPSWEEP_API_KEY }}
    run: ./gradlew uploadToAppSweepRelease
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you've added the plugin to your build.gradle files.